# Axis dir=reverse and colormap bug (?) in Tikz

Tags: pgfplots

I'm fairly new to this, so I might just be missing something obvious. I've been doing some research but found nothing much so far. For some reason, the y-axis is by default displayed pointing to the 'negative' direction. I figured I'd just flip the axis, but when I did, it looks as though it's the point of view that is being swapped rather than the axis, and that we're looking at the 'behind the scenes' for the dual-colormap trick. Any thoughts?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}   
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,3d,arrows}
\usepackage{pgfplots}       



\begin{document}



\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9]
        \begin{axis}[
                    axis lines=center, axis on top,
                    xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty,ztick=\empty,
                    enlargelimits=true 
                    ]
%
  \addplot3[
            surf,
            mesh/interior colormap name=hot,
            colormap/blackwhite,
            shader=flat, 
            fill opacity=0.7
            ] 
                {x^2-y^2};
%
        \end{axis}
%
\end{tikzpicture}
%
%
\quad
%
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9]
        \begin{axis}[
                    axis lines=center, axis on top,
                    xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty,ztick=\empty,
                    y dir=reverse,
                    enlargelimits=true 
                    ]
%
  \addplot3[
            surf,
            mesh/interior colormap name=hot,
            colormap/blackwhite,
            shader=flat, 
            fill opacity=0.7
            ] 
                {x^2-y^2};
%
        \end{axis}
%
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The axes are drawn according to the right handedness. That's why it is pointing towards inside.

You are not changing only the axis direction but also changing the order of the z buffer too. So the viewpoint doesn't move but the whole surface does and also it is an overkill.

The simple solutions are

- Change the axis line style by replacing `y dir=reverse` with

  ```
  y axis line style=latex-
  ```
- Change the view point

  ```
  view={155}{30}
  ```

Comment: Christophe - Wow, that was quick, thanks a lot! Works just fine. (Realized in the meantime, btw, that the y axis was in fact not pointing to negative values - my bad :S )